# problem in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this jquery function to send a request to abc.php;
The value of x returned is correct but whatever be it value, only the if is executed; even if x is false, else is not executed.

```
$.post('abc.php',{u:e1.value},function(x){
document.getElementById('d').innerHTML+=" x="+x;
if(x){
    document.getElementById('d').style.color="green";
    document.getElementById('d').innerHTML+="<img src='t.jpeg'>";
    q=true;
    }
else{
    document.getElementById('d').style.color="red";
    document.getElementById('d').innerHTML+="U";
    q=false;
    }document.getElementById('f').innerHTML+=" q="+q;
    });
}
```

This is the file abc.php;

```
<?php
$db = "b";
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$q = "select * from us where ad='$_POST[u]'";

$r=mysql_query($q, $link) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($r)==1)
echo true;
else echo false;
mysql_close($link) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you are checking is a **string** not a boolean.

You test should be: `x === "true"` (although you may need to account for whitespace in the output of the PHP.

Comment: I changed the code to check for string but there's still a prob.
Its probably because of the white space.

x = jQuery.trim($(this).text());
x = x.replace(/ /g,'');
x = jQuery.trim(x);
x = $(this).text().replace(/ /g,'');

I tried some of the to strip the whitespaces. But doesn't seem to work, the whitespace remains. Why is that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you're echoing out the variable so the data is seen as a string therefore if it is "true" or "false" the variable is always set, meaning x is true.

Try changing your statement to if(x.toLowerCase() == "true")

You can add a further = to check it is indeed a string

Answer (score 0):

The data is taken as string, not boolean.
and moreover you are echoing booleans instead of strings .

http://codepad.org/KCROfdqq

```
<?php

echo "true";   //  output : true

echo true ;   // output : 1


?>
```

So try these changes :

PHP:

```
  echo "true" ;
 and echo "false";
```

Javascript:

```
 if(x == 'true')
```

Comment: i made the change, but it did not solve the problem; could it be because of whitespaces?